# Uncaught exception before SurfaceView is created - Android - video playback

Tags: android, video, surfaceview

I'm trying to do some video playback with a very simple code, and no matter what I change, I'm getting always the same problem: The last line on onCreate and onResume is called, but nothing else is called and Activity finishes with an uncaught exception, before calling surfaceCreated.
What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;


public class VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private SurfaceView vview;
private SurfaceHolder holder;
private String videoPath;
private String id;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.videoplayer);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    System.out.println("Inside VideoPlayerActivity.");

    vview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.vplay_surface);
    holder = vview.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    System.out.println("Surface and holder configured.");

    //Bundle dungle = getIntent().getExtras();
    //id = dungle.getString("id");
    id = "1";

    videoPath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath().toString() + File.separator + "VID" + id + ".mp4";
    System.out.println("PATH: " + videoPath);
    //iniElements();

    } 

@Override
public void onResume() {
    iniElements();
}

private void iniElements() {

    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    System.out.println("MediaPlayer object created.");

    } 

private void iniPlayer() {

    System.out.println("Initiating player!");

    try {
    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(videoPath);
    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mMediaPlayer.start();

    System.out.println("Reached START PLAYER.");

}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    System.out.println("Surface changed.");

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    System.out.println("Surface created!");
    try {
        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Elements configured.");

    iniPlayer();

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    System.out.println("Surface destroyed.");

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    System.out.println("Activity on pause.");
}


@Override
public void onDestroy () {
    System.out.println("Destroying activity.");
}


}
```

And the xml file is as simple as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="268dp"
        android:layout_height="202dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/vplay_surface"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:gravity="center" />

  </RelativeLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Logcat says:

```
05-06 16:39:51.286: INFO/power(2083): *** acquire_dvfs_lock : lockType : 1  freq : 1200000 
05-06 16:39:51.286: INFO/ActivityManager(2083): START {intent.toShortString} from pid 18751
05-06 16:39:51.286: DEBUG/PowerManagerService(2083): acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1200000  uid : 1000  pid : 2083  tag : ActivityManager
05-06 16:39:51.286: WARN/ActivityManager(2083): mDVFSLock.acquire()
  05-06 16:39:51.306: DEBUG/ActivityManager(2083): Trying to launch applicationName
  05-06 16:39:51.326: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(18751): Shutting down VM
  05-06 16:39:51.326: WARN/dalvikvm(18751): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c341f8)
  05-06 16:39:51.331: WARN/ActivityManager(2083):   Force finishing activity r.intent.getComponent().flattenToShortString()
05-06 16:39:51.336: VERBOSE/yamaha::media::VolumeCtrl(1833): VolumeCtrl::createVolume()
05-06 16:39:51.336: DEBUG/yamaha::media::VolumeCtrl(1833): Dir0      : AP Playback Music SP (0001h)
05-06 16:39:51.336: DEBUG/yamaha::media::VolumeCtrl(1833): Dir0Att   : AP Playback Music SP (0001h)
05-06 16:39:51.336: DEBUG/yamaha::media::VolumeCtrl(1833): DacMaster : AP Playback Music SP (0001h)
05-06 16:39:51.336: DEBUG/yamaha::media::VolumeCtrl(1833): Sp        : AP Playback Music SP (FD81h)
05-06 16:39:51.336: VERBOSE/yamaha::media::VolumeCtrl(1833): VolumeCtrl::setVolume()
05-06 16:39:51.336: DEBUG/yamaha::media::VolumeCtrl(1833): VolumeCtrl::setVolume() FM Playback: Ready
05-06 16:39:51.336: DEBUG/yamaha::media::VolumeCtrl(1833): VolumeCtrl::setVolume() VoiceCall: Ready
05-06 16:39:51.336: WARN/ActivityManager(2083):   Force finishing activity r.intent.getComponent().flattenToShortString()
05-06 16:39:51.351: INFO/dumpstate(18883): Check if stand-alone
05-06 16:39:51.356: INFO/dumpstate(18883): begin
05-06 16:39:51.401: INFO/ALSAModule(1833): Initialized ALSA PLAYBACK device hifi
05-06 16:39:51.641: INFO/AudioPolicyManager(1833): stopOutput() output 1, stream 1, session 2190
05-06 16:39:51.681: INFO/AudioFlinger(1833): stop output streamType (0, 1) for 1
05-06 16:39:51.836: WARN/ActivityManager(2083): Activity pause timeout for r
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you posted the correct portion of logcat...there's no exception there...

Comment: There is the uncaught exception there!! I don't know where to catch it because I don't know where it happens! onCreate() Finishes OK (I see the System.out), onResume() finishes OK, and then, the app finishes with the uncaught exception, and it doesn't enter surfaceCreated() or onDestroy() or nothing, it just crashes with the uncaught exception (05-06 16:39:51.326)!!
Help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I found the problem. The problem is that you cannot open a file inside /data/data/package in such manner. You have to first create a FileInputStream with openFileInput() and then create a File with reference to the FileInputStream; then you can use that File to get its File Descriptor and pass it to the player.
If you want to see the code, please ask for it, I will share it.
Cheers